# Python SQL execution fails randomly with Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python

I am executing some sqls in loop . mostly the code works fine and completes the loop. But some time python fails with Traceback issue after 2-3 hours. When i checked the SQL execution in DB, it executed but python did not continue the next execution loop and got stuck. Throws the error after 2 hours

**Executing SQL**  :

```
sql = f.read() 
cursor.execute(sql)
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb.py", line 480, in __exit__
    self.rollback()
  File "/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgdb.py", line 519, in rollback
    raise _op_error("can't rollback")
pg.OperationalError: can't rollback
```

**Here is the full code in loop:**

```
dt = new_execution_timestamp_for(job, dependencies, cursor)

if dt is not None:


logging.info("Running job %s", job)
with open(os.path.join(os.environ['ROOT'],
                       "share", job + ".sql")) as f:
    sql = f.read()
    if weekly is None or weekly == date.today().weekday():
        if loops is not None:
            loop_items = fetch_list("loops", loops, cursor)
            timestamp = fetch_job_timestamp(job, cursor)
            for item in loop_items:
                cursor.execute(sql, {loops: item, 
                                     'last_executed': timestamp})
        else:
            cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.execute(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, (dt, job))
else:

logging.info("Skipping job %s", job)
```

Comment: You'll have to isolate more relevant code and post it. You've removed what maybe relevant lines from the traceback, there's no idea what the sql queries you're executing are, or nor what `fetch_list` or `fetch_job_timestamp` do... And if it's periodic - then it could be a system thing and maybe not even something to do with your code...

Comment: @JonClements : I dont think there is a problem with sql because the same sql  executes fine and sometimes fails with this message.

Comment: Data can't be causing constraint issues etc...?

Comment: @JonClements , there is no constrain in the table